# How to write code themeforest quality standards?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm planning to sell bootstrap templates on themeforest market.
My first template has been rejected already. I think a problem is in code structure and organization.

Can you share some books or video cources that will be helpful to write code according to Themeforest quality standart?

Example of my codding style

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Agency FB", sans-serif;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

span {
  color: red;
}

blockquote {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;   
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  padding: 0.25em 40px;
  line-height: 1.45;
  position: relative;
  color: #777;
  text-align: left;
}

blockquote:after {
  display: block;
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
  color: #999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

::selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; /* Safari */
  color: white;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; /* Firefox */
  color: white;
}

::-webkit-selection {
  background: #ffb7b7;
  color: white;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
  .navbar {
    padding: 20px 0;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
  }

  .top-nav-collapse {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

/* override bootstrap default navbar
=======================================================*/
.navbar-fixed-top {
  background-color: #333;
  border: none;
}

.navbar .nav > li a:hover{
  color: white;
}

.navbar .nav .active > a, .navbar .nav .active > a:hover, .navbar .nav .active > a:active {
  background-color: #333;
  color: red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.navbar .nav li ul li a:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
}

.navbar .nav li ul li a:active {
  background: #333;
  color: red;
}

/* btn-default 
=======================================================*/
.btn-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #ccc;
  color: red;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
  transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, transform 2s;
}

/* start intro-section
=======================================================*/
.intro-section {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parallax-header-layers li{
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* start about-section
=======================================================*/
.about-section {
  color: white;
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.team-profile {
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

.team-profile img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.team-profile i {
  color: grey;
  width: 15px;
}

.team-profile i:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- font-awesome css -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

  </head>

  <!-- The #page-top ID is part of the scrolling feature - the data-spy and data-target are part of the built-in Bootstrap scrollspy function -->

  <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Template</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
            <li class="hidden">
              <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="page-scroll" href="#clients">Clients</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Intro Section -->
    <section id="intro" class="intro-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">

            <ul id="port" class="parallax-header-layers">
              <li class="parallax-layer"><img src="../img/header/parallax/pen.png" alt="" /></li>
              <li class="parallax-layer"><img src="../img/header/parallax/phone.png" alt=""/></li>
              <li class="parallax-layer"><img src="../img/header/parallax/mac.png" alt="" /></li>

            </ul>

            <a class="btn btn-default page-scroll" href="#about">Click Me to Scroll Down!</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- About Section -->
    <section id="about" class="about-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Our <span>team</span></h1>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 team-profile">
                <img src="../img/team-section/photo-1.jpg">
                <h4>Anton Vetrov <span>Developer</span></h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 team-profile">
                <img src="../img/team-section/photo-3.jpg">
                <h4>Anton Vetrov <span>Developer</span></h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 team-profile">
                <img src="../img/team-section/photo-1.jpg">
                <h4>Anton Vetrov <span>Developer</span></h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 team-profile">
                <img src="../img/team-section/photo-3.jpg">
                <h4>Anton Vetrov <span>Developer</span></h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Services Section -->
    <section id="services" class="services-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 development-section row pull-right">
            <h1>Developer <span>Section</span></h1>
            <p>
              A brand is only as successfulas its implementation. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non     proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.    
            </p>
          </div>



          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 design-section row pull-left">
            <h1>Services <span>Section</span></h1>
            <p>
              A brand is only as successfulas its implementation. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
              quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non     proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.    
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Have you ever asked Themeforest ?

Comment: They do not provide an example of coding. that is why i'm asking professionals here to help me

Comment: If a template market does not provide guidance, then I strongly recommend picking another one

Answer (score -1):

Judging by your code provided I would say it's not completely valid by the BS standards.

Some notices:

- The BS classes are not used like should, ie. in the Services
  section you have a col-lg-6 div inside of a col-lg-12 div, without
  row div. Always try to use the order container > row > col-XX-Y.
- About sections' divs are a bit messy when there's col-lg-X divs
  inside of another col-lg-Y. You could put the section title in a div of it own and the start a new row for the team members.
- Also it's a good practice to use content divs, for example in the
  About sections' Team members, there could be divs like team-member-img,
  team-member-name etc. It gives more control over given content.

I don't know for sure that these are the reasons for rejection but they give the code more structure and make it understandable and it's easier to manage by the users/buyers.

---

Original post reformatted:

ThemeForest has guides for templating. General Guide:

https://help.market.envato.com/hc/en-us/articles/202500774-ThemeForest-General-File-Preparation-Guidelines

Specified ones (including "Bootstrap Skins Category Submission Requirements"):

https://help.market.envato.com/hc/en-us/sections/200615794-ThemeForest-Requirements

I would recommend going through your code and fixing it by the BS standards. Good way for understanding the good practices is to debug some best selling premium templates. And always remember to make sure that the HTML and CSS is valid.

Comment: I know about requirements,but if you read them, you will  not see peaces of code..There is just a requirement professional style and clean code

Comment: Well I think nobody can help you here without seeing a single line of your code so best way to get any tips is to give us a look. You can also try searching for something like "Best coding practices" if you're not familiar with those.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: There's some comments of the code now in my original post.